# URL route rule for anything before url

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I want to write a rule for url that anything comes before

/analysis should navigate me to appropriate place.

For that I written code in web.config as below :-

```
<rule name="Analysis Routes">
                    <match url="(/.*)(/analysis)" />
                  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                  </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
```

But it is giving me error Page not found after hitting url :-

```
url/analysis
```

I wanted to set rule as :- url can be anything.

```
stackoverflow.com/analysis

somesite.com/analysis
```

there can be anything before /analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below rule checks if requested path has exactly analysis , and if succeeds then it does a redirect to specified Url.

**Example:** http://example.com/analysis to http://example.com/

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect Before Analysis" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^analysis" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Refrences:

[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

[2](https://nicolas.guelpa.me/blog/2015/02/21/rewrite-redirect-iis.html)